# Создание лайков с помощью переключения класса во vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, like

В данном массиве, который находится в ленте выводятся посты.

```
data() {
  return {
    header: {

    },
    footer: {

    },
    posts: [
      {
        id: 1,
        content: 'Текст первого поста',
        photo: PostSea,
        likesCount: 12,
        activeClass: 'active_like',
        isActive: false

      },
      {
        id: 2,
        content: 'Текст второго поста',
        photo: PostSea,
        likesCount: 12,
        activeClass: 'active_like',
        isActive: false
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        content: 'Текст третьего поста',
        photo: PostSea,
        likesCount: 12,
        activeClass: 'active_like',
        isActive: false
      }
     ]
```

В самом посте в блоке actions находится блок like, в котором две иконки, которые при клике должны меняться, то есть пустой лайк должен становиться красным.

```
<div class="col-1 like">
    <i @click="isActive = !isActive" class="material-icons like_icon" :class="{ active: isActive }">favorite_border</i>
    <i class="material-icons active_like" style="display: none">favorite</i>
  </div>
```

Нужно сделать переключение лайков. Пока новичок в использовании vue, надеюсь на вашу помощь, спасибо!

Comment: А почему бы в классе `active` не написать вывод полного лайка? Есть - выводится полный. Нет - подложка показывает своё (рамку лайка?).

Comment: То есть в пустой иконке :class="{ active: 'active_like' }?

Comment: Советую использовать условный оператор `v-if` / `v-else` : https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-else